# Can I transfer my PC account to PS4

Tags: pc, ps4, grand-theft-auto-v

I bought a PS4 version of GTA5.. And I want to ask you if I can transfer my stuff from PC to PS4

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Online or Single Player? I guess it's about Online, but I'll write in both modes.

- If Online: You cannot transfer anything from PC to PS4.
- If Single Player: You can transfer the save game using the **Save Wizard** and **Save Editor** programs. On [this website](https://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/howto-convert-gta-v-sp-pc-saves-to-ps4-saves.1733546/) you will find two ways to do it (I don't want to do copy/paste here).